# Angular ngIf with multiple matches not working

Tags: angular

I have a weird issue with my ngIf.

Here is my ngIf statement which works perfectly like this.

```
ngIf="this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value == 4
```

However I now need to add more values to it and when I do it, the statement seems to break. 
So when I do this:

```
ngIf="this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value == 4 || this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value == 6"
```

it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code with one condition probably doesn't work either.

Remove `this` from template:

```
*ngIf="offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value == 4"
```

or

```
*ngIf="offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value == 4 || offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value == 6"
```